# User defined Listener in Java

Tags: java

In my web app, during some change over the object, i need to send a mail about the changes happened in the object. 
My question is how to write a listener for this.
Please give me some article regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: try searching for "custom event in java"

Comment: Can you modify the source code of the objects class? IAW, can you make that class observable or do we need a separate Observer for that object?

Comment: Bro it was good question really useful +1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A typical implementation could be like this: your object is observable. So every time, one of the (observed) values changes, an event is fired and all registered listeners are notified. One of those listeners now would be designed to take the notification and create and send an EMail (Java Mail API)

Let's take a sample bean which we make observable:

```
public class Bean implements Observable{

  // code to maintain listeners
  private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
  public void add(Listener listener) {listeners.add(listener);}
  public void remove(Listener listener) {listeners.remove(listener);}

  // a sample field
  private int field;
  public int getField() {return field;}
  public int setField(int value) {
    field = value;
    fire("field");        
  }

  // notification code
  private void fire(String attribute) {
    for (Listener listener:listeners) {
      fieldChanged(this, attribute);
    }
  }
}
```

The Listener interface:

```
public interface Listener {
  public void fieldChanged(Object source, String attrbute);
}
```

The Observable interface:

```
public interface Observable {
  public void add(Listener listener);
  public void remove(Listener listener);
}
```

And the EMailer:

```
public class Sender implements Listener {

  public void register(Observable observable) {observable.add(this);}
  public void unregister(Observable observable) {observable.remove(this);}

  public void fieldChanged(Object source, String attribute) {
    sendEmail(source, attribute); // this has to be implemented
  }

}
```

**EDIT**
Corrected an ugly mistake in the setter method - now the event is fired **after** the property has been set. Was the other way round, with the side effect, that if a listener read the changed property, he still saw the old, unchanged value...

Comment: I would advise using a CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener> rather than ArrayList<Listener>.  Otherwise a listener implementation can potentially remove itself during a notification resulting in a ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 6):

If you simply wish to know about the properties of an object being modified I would recommend using a [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html).  That way you can use the [`PropertyChangeSupport`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) utility class to manage your listener instances and the firing of events.  You also avoid reinventing the wheel.

For more bespoke event firing I would recommend defining your own listener interface.

**Example Class**

```
public class MyBean {
  private final PropertyChangeSupport support;

  private int i;
  private boolean b;

  public MyBean() {
    this.support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
  }

  // Accessors and Mutators.  Mutating a property causes a PropertyChangeEvent
  // to be fired.
  public int getI() { return i; }

  public void setI(int i) {
    int oldI = this.i;
    this.i = i;
    support.firePropertyChange("i", oldI, this.i);
  }

  public boolean getB() { return b; }

  public void setB(boolean b) {
    boolean oldB = this.b;
    this.b = b;
    support.firePropertyChange("b", oldB, this.b);
  }

  // Wrapper methods that simply delegate listener management to
  // the underlying PropertyChangeSupport class.
  public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    support.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
  }

  public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener l) {
    // You would typically call this method rather than addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener)
    // in order to register your listener with a specific property.
    // This then avoids the need for large if-then statements within your listener
    // implementation in order to check which property has changed.

    if (!"i".equals(propertyName) && !"b".equals(propertyName)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
    }

    support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, l);
  }

  public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
    support.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
  }

  public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener l) {
    support.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, l);
  }
}
```

Example Usage

```
// Create a new instance of our observable MyBean class.
MyBean bean = new MyBean();

// Create a PropertyChangeListener specifically for listening to property "b".
PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    assert "b".equals(evt.getPropertyName());
    boolean oldB = (Boolean) evt.getOldValue();
    boolean newB = (Boolean) evt.getNewValue();

    System.err.println(String.format("Property b updated: %b -> %b, oldB, newB));
  }
}

// Register listener with specific property name.  It will only be called back
// if this property changes, *not* the "i" int property.
bean.addPropertyChangeListener("b", listener);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **[Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)**. This pattern uses these classes :

- [java.util.Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)
- [java.util.Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)

Here is an example.

The observer :

```
public class EmailObserver implements Observer
{
    @Override
    public void update(Observable obj, Object arg)
    {
        if (obj instanceof YourObject)
        {
            // TODO Send the mail or whatever, you have access to the modified object through obj
            // In arg you can put some additional parameter, like the modified field
        }
    }
}
```

The Observable Object :

```
public static class YourObject extends Observable
{
    public void setSomething(Object parameter)
    {
        // TODO some modification in YourObject

        setChanged(); // From Observable : the object has changed
        notifyObservers(parameter); // Notify the observer about the change
    }
}
```

And the main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Create YourObject
    YourObject o = new YourObject();

    // create an observer
    EmailObserver emailObserver = new EmailObserver();

    // subscribe the observer to your object
    o.addObserver(emailObserver);

    // Now you can modify your object, changes will be notified by email
    o.setSomething(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Observer design pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.
http://java-x.blogspot.com/2007/01/implementing-observer-pattern-in-java.html